# Trying to set up a mail server in OpenBSD: doveadm auth login fails

Tags: imap, dovecot, openbsd, vultr, opensmtpd

I set up an OpenBSD 7.0 instance on Vultr in order to get a mail server running with Dovecot and OpenSMTPD.  I (mostly) followed the instructions [here](https://www.vultr.com/docs/an-openbsd-e-mail-server-using-opensmtpd-dovecot-rspamd-and-rainloop/) and [here](https://poolp.org/posts/2019-09-14/setting-up-a-mail-server-with-opensmtpd-dovecot-and-rspamd/) and a bit [here](https://karchnu.fr/posts/2020-09-17-certificate-smtp-imap-antispam.html).

I set it up to use with virtual mail, creating files in '/etc/mail/virtual' and '/etc/mail/credentials' with a single virtual user:  'user@domain.ca::vmail:2000:2000:/var/vmail/domain.ca/user::userdb_mail=maildir:/var/vmail/domain.ca/user'

I created the encrypted password with 'smtpctl encrypt' and pasted it where it should be in the credentials file.

However, running 'doveadm auth login user@domain.ca' fails.

In /var/log/maillog I get:

```
 Jan 25 14:06:58 vultrBSD dovecot: auth-worker(165): conn unix:auth-worker (pid=44111,uid=518): auth-worker<1>: bsdauth(user@domain.ca): unknown user
Jan 25 14:06:58 vultrBSD dovecot: auth: passwd-file(user@domain.ca): Password mismatch
```

I know the password is correct, and I tried changing it and pasting in a new one that I created with 'smtpctl encrypt', but still the same error.  The '/etc/mail/credentials' file is set to 0440 and owned by _smtpd:_dovecot.  Even temporarily setting it to 0777 doesn't work.

I can send mail to the server from another account, I see that is shows up in '/var/vmail/domain.ca/user/new'  but I am unable to connect my Thunderbird client to the server.  Attempting to set up a new mail account in Thunderbird doesn't seem to work, Thunderbird rejects the password (although it does detect the correct protocols and ports, IMAP/SMTP).

Here is the local.conf file in /etc/dovecot:

```
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain
first_valid_uid = 2000
first_valid_gid = 2000
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
mail_plugin_dir = /usr/local/lib/dovecot
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex  imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext imapsieve vnd.dovecot.imapsieve
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
mmap_disable = yes

namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Archive {
  auto = subscribe
  special_use = \Archive
  }
  mailbox Drafts {
  auto = subscribe
  special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
  auto = subscribe
  special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
  auto = subscribe
  special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
  auto = subscribe
  special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}

plugin {
  imapsieve_mailbox1_before = file:/usr/local/lib/dovecot/sieve/report-spam.sieve
  imapsieve_mailbox1_causes = COPY
  imapsieve_mailbox1_name = Junk
  imapsieve_mailbox2_before = file:/usr/local/lib/dovecot/sieve/report-ham.sieve
  imapsieve_mailbox2_causes = COPY
  imapsieve_mailbox2_from = Junk
  imapsieve_mailbox2_name = *
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_global_extensions = +vnd.dovecot.pipe +vnd.dovecot.environment
  sieve_pipe_bin_dir = /usr/local/lib/dovecot/sieve
  sieve_plugins = sieve_imapsieve sieve_extprograms
}

protocols = imap sieve
service imap-login {
    inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
  }
}

service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
  }
  inet_listener sieve_deprecated {
    port = 2000
  }
}

ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/domain.ca.fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/domain.ca.key

userdb {
  args = username_format=%u /etc/mail/credentials
  driver = passwd-file
  name =
}
passdb {
  args = scheme=CRYPT username_format=%u /etc/mail/credentials
  driver = passwd-file
  name =
}

protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = " imap_sieve"
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this and know of a fix?

Thanks.

Comment: While I do not have an answer for your issues with connecting to `dovecot`, note that Vultr has their own configuration of OpenBSD that the project is not expecting that may be destroyed with future patches or upgrades. The way to prevent this from happening is from console run `bsd.rd` and then reinstall (configuring however you desire).

Comment: I've narrowed things down a little.  The issue seems to be with the encryption scheme used by dovecot vs. the scheme used by SMTPD.  

If I use 'smtpctl encrypt' to create an encrypted password I can authenticate with the SMTPD daemon, but not dovecot. If I use 'doveadm pw' to create the password I can authenticate with dovecot, but not SMTPD.  

I was under the impression that both smtpctl and doveadm used blowfish schemes.  Is this not true?  Is there a way to get either SMTPD or dovecot to read the other's scheme?

Answer (score 0):

Hashed strings, including passwords, typically use several layers besides the base hashing algorithm. Two different implementations (dovecot vs smtpd) using the same hashing algorithm will output two different hashes given the same input (password.)

This is due to what is called salt and pepper. Salt is a randomly generated string usually based on some user data as the seed. This salt is then inserted into the password in a way dictated by the implementation (dovecot or smtpd) before hashing the password.

Similarly, pepper is a string dictated by the implementation and inserted into the password before hashing. This combination of salting and peppering creates a unique hash per implementation which makes storing passwords safer. This makes it so that a cracker can't easily compare hashes from several sites or programs to crack user passwords and break into all instances of that password simultaneously.

This is why you can't reuse a password hash stored by one program to unlock the same password when used by another program. Even if both programs use identical hashing algorithms.

The fix should be to set up the credentials individually for each program and not reuse each other's hashes.